# "but the compiler doesn't know this" - what's the sense?

Tags: java, java-9

I've met a such kind of code and comments in the `java.util.ImmutableCollections` class:

```
static final class List0<E> extends AbstractImmutableList<E> {
    ...
    @Override
    public E get(int index) {
        Objects.checkIndex(index, 0); // always throws IndexOutOfBoundsException
        return null;                  // but the compiler doesn't know this
    } 
    ...
}
```

Why not just `throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(...)`? What's the reason?

Comment: @YCF_L not really... https://stackoverflow.com/a/48215005/1059372

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps, it is just an avoiding of a code duplication, because otherwise it would be something like:

```
new IndexOutOfBoundsException(outOfBoundsMessage(..., ...))
```

but `outOfBounds*` methods are `private`, so by design somebody should call wrappers like `return Preconditions.checkIndex(index, length, null)`

Comment: Yes, avoiding code duplication. There is an effort towards centralizing all of these index checking and exception message constructions. That does not only affect collection implementations and `Arrays` utility methods, but also NIO buffers, `CharSequence` implementations and so on. Lots of places, lots of code duplication. Note that this is a [new API method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#checkIndex-int-int-) that allows your application to participate in this central handling. Still, I would use `throw new AssertionError()` instead of `return null;` here…

Comment: O master @Holger, I appreciate your appreciation of my answer and yours additional comment. Yours authoritative opinion is also very needed in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48227496/reference-to-method-is-ambiguous-when-migrating-from-java8-to-java9

Answer (score 3):

Unless I'm missing something obvious here, this is much simpler. It's the same thing as:

```
// this will not compile, *even* if test throws the Exception always
public String s() {
    test(); 
}

private void test() {
    throw new RuntimeException("just because");
}
```

The compiler can't tell that `test` will always throw the `RuntimeException` so it requires a `return` statement in `s()`. Same thing happens in `switch` statements for an enum, where you have to provide a `throw`; even if you have handled all the cases of that enum.

---

This code btw is used in `List0`, where it does not make sense to call `get(x)`, because there are no elements in the List for sure.

Comment: You can always write `public String s() { throw new RuntimeException("aaa"); }` what is 100% valid and compilable code

Answer (score 2):

The implementation seems more design-oriented than just functionality here.

The reasons for the same could primarily be that the `Preconditions.checkIndex` is marked as an `@HotSpotIntrinsicCandidate` which means a code performance improvement is sought while this method is used internally.

Also, can notice that all the immutable list - containing 0(empty),1, 2 or N elements, created using the factory method `of` makes use of the [`Objects.checkIndex(int index, int length)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#checkIndex-int-int-) which eventually relies on the above method call to possibly make some internal optimisations.

---

Brief over `HotSpotIntrinsicCandidate` from the library :-

> The `@HotSpotIntrinsicCandidate` annotation is specific to the 
>    HotSpot Virtual Machine. It indicates that an annotated method may be (but is not guaranteed to be) intrinsified by the HotSpot VM.
>
> A method is intrinsified if the HotSpot VM replaces the annotated
>   method with hand-written assembly and/or hand-written compiler IR
>   -- a compiler intrinsic -- to improve performance.
>
> The `@HotSpotIntrinsicCandidate` annotation is internal to the Java
>   libraries and is therefore not supposed to have any relevance for
>   application code.

Comment: if you mentioned `@HotSpotIntrinsicCandidate` you could have mentioned `@ForceInline` for `Objects.checkIndex`. Also, this is interesting as *how* exactly is a CPU going to optimize this call being intrinsic; I don't know that btw

Comment: @Eugene `ForceInline` seems to be focussing on ignoring the metrics of annotated methods hence avoided bringing it into the discussion. Haven't digged into the implementation of the `HotSpotIntrinsicCandidate` myself yet as well.

Comment: there is not much to see under the implementation... :) it's just an annotation, you would have to dig the jvm source filed and see what is *particularly*  done for that method...